# Rounding float numbers in Hive, Hue

Tags: hive, floating-point

I have a problem when casting and rounding to float in HIVE, 
I have string fields that I want to cast it to float with 3 decimal digits, but it shows always the entire float without rounding it.

Example:

```
`select round(cast(regexp_replace( '1,1111', ',' , '.') as float),3)`
```

that gives as result 
`1.1109999418258667`

while: 
    `select round(1.1111 ,3)` gives

`1.111`  which is the wanted result.

PS.I am using Hue editor.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to get the expected result casting to double

```
select round(cast(regexp_replace( '1,1111', ',' , '.') as double),3);
```

Comment: Thank you , but is this a good method, because I have two tables source table and target with the same data, the first has all data with string type and the target table has the correct types which is float for this column , so I shoud cast string values to float not to double.